# Get object of ribbon button in JavaScript

Tags: 2010, javascript, client-object-model, ribbon

I am trying to access the ribbon button via JavaScript. Below is my code:

```
// Get the page manager
var ribbonPageMgr = SP.Ribbon.PageManager.get_instance();
// Get the ribbon
var ribbon = ribbonPageMgr.get_ribbon();

// Get the tab in which button resides
var ribbonTab = ribbon.getChild("Ribbon.List"); // CUI.Tab
// Get the group in tab in which button resides
var ribbonGroup = ribbonTab.getChild("Ribbon.List.Settings"); // CUI.Group
```

In my case the ribbon button resides in the "List" tab under the "Settings" group. But I am stuck after this point. From whatever resources I could find on the web I have come to conclusion that a ribbon button resides in following containers:

> CUI.Tab --> CUI.Group --> CUI.Layout --> CUI.Section

How do I proceed to find `CUI.Layout`, `CUI.Section` and eventually my ribbon button? Is this the correct way that I am following?

Comment: What exactly you want to do with the Ribbon button.? you can find the button by using only jquery (need not use sp.js) and you can hide/show, rename, any other operation etc.. Read below post , might be helpful for you. [How-to-hide-ribbon-in-sharepoint using jquery](http://spshell.blogspot.in/2014/11/how-to-hide-ribbon-in-sharepoint.html)

Comment: @Vikas: My intention is to get the custom ribbon button object and set its properties like `ToolTipTitle`, `ToolTipDescription` and [**more**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff458366(v=office.15).aspx). These properties need to be set dynamically. Can this be done via jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is not working as you expect. After investigating it, please look at the DOM with developer tools. Basically the group is a li tag. After that, if you want to make it work you must get as many childs as needed following all span id's.

Answer (score 0):

In `CUI.Group` you can look into `$6_0`, then `$1j_0`, where you can find also the `CUI.Layout` stored in `$4_0`.

After that, just add `.getChild` on your `CUI.Group` with the name of your `CUI.Layout`.

The same is for `CUI.Section`.